# RemoveAccessRule c# not removing username from security (folder properties)

Tags: c#, directory-security

I am new to Stack Overflow - So be nice :)

Have a question, I have been learning c# on an off for about a year now on and off (first language), I have created a project that created folders and assigns permissions to a user based on their username from AD.  Which appears as a seperate process in a checklistbox.

I have managed to assign rules etc and it grants this user rights over the folder, I have tried to expand on this by attempting to remove their rights.  I have done this using RemoteAcessRule but this only removes the acess (as you would expect) but the user still appears in seucirty just with NO permissions at all.  My question is what is needed to remove the user from here programtically.

I can post code snipetts if needed,

Thanks,